# Perl - passing an open socket across fork/exec

Tags: perl, sockets, exec, fork

I want to have a Perl daemon **listen** for and **accept** an incoming connection from a client, and then **fork** & **exec** another Perl program to continue the conversation with the client.

I can do this fine when simply forking - where the daemon code also contains the child's code.  But I don't see how the open socket can be "passed" across an exec() to another Perl program.

Somehow I got the impression that this was easy in Unix (which is my environment) and therefore in Perl, too.  Can it actually be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done in approximately three steps:

1. Clear the *close-on-exec* flag on the file descriptor.
2. Tell the exec'd program which file descriptor to use.
3. Restore the file descriptor into a handle.

**1.** Perl (by default) sets the close-on-exec flag on file descriptors it opens. This means file descriptors won't be preserved across an `exec`. You have to clear this flag first:

```
use Fcntl;

my $flags = fcntl $fh, F_GETFD, 0 or die "fcntl F_GETFD: $!";
fcntl $fh, F_SETFD, $flags & ~FD_CLOEXEC or die "fcntl F_SETFD: $!";
```

**2.** Now that the file descriptor will stay open across `exec`, you need to tell the program which descriptor it is:

```
my $fd = fileno $fh;
exec 'that_program', $fd;  # pass it on the command line
# (you could also pass it via %ENV or whatever)
```

**3.** Recover the filehandle on the other side:

```
my $fd = $ARGV[0];  # or however you passed it
open my $fh, '+<&=', $fd;  # fdopen
$fh->autoflush(1);  # because "normal" sockets have that enabled by default
```

Now you have a Perl-level handle in `$fh` again.

*Addendum:* As ikegami mentioned in a comment, you can also make sure the socket is using one of the three "standard" file descriptors (0 (stdin), 1 (stdout), 2 (stderr)) which are 1. left open by default across execs, 2. have known numbers so no need to pass anything, and 3. perl will create corresponding handles for them automatically.

```
open STDIN, '+<&', $fh;  # now STDIN refers to the socket
exec 'that_program';
```

Now `that_program` can simply use `STDIN`. This works even for output; there is no inherent restriction on file descriptors 0, 1, 2 that they be for input or output only. It's just a convention that all unix programs follow.

Comment: I'm about to try out your procedure, but I have a question about using STDIN: can it be bound to a bi-directional connection such as a socket?  I tend to think of fds 0-2 as semi-magical (specialized in some way for terminal I/O).  Are they really special other than in the ways you mentioned in your addendum?

Comment: The problem I'm having with your solution has to do with opening the FD for both input and output.  `open my $fh, '<&=', $fd;` just opens it for input.  I tried following this with `open $fh, '>&=', $fd;` but it get the error: Bad file descriptor.  (The preceding open for input works.)  I can't find any info about how to open for both input and output.

Comment: Another followup: the open (for bidirectional i/o) should have been `open $fh, '+>&=', $fd;`.  Also, I needed to issue `$fh->autoflush(1)`.

Comment: Correction to 'open' flags: `open $fh, '+<&=', $fd;`